# How to pass parameter to wizard

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I have a wizard called "ui.wizard.new.project" which will be launched by the command service framework programmatically like below. However, how do I pass parameters to the "ui.wizard.new.project" wizard under this framework?

```
IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
ICommandService commandService = (ICommandService) window.getService(ICommandService.class);
IHandlerService handlerService = (IHandlerService)window.getService(IHandlerService.class);
org.eclipse.core.commands.Command newProjectCmd = commandService.getCommand("org.eclipse.ui.newWizard");
IParameter param = newProjectCmd.getParameter("newWizardId");
Parameterization parm = new Parameterization(param, "ui.wizard.new.project");
ParameterizedCommand parmCommand = new ParameterizedCommand(newProjectCmd, new Parameterization[] { parm });
handlerService.executeCommand(parmCommand, null);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to pass parameters to the wizard through the command parameters.

The only input to wizard is the `IWorkbenchWizard.init` method call with the workbench and the current selection.